# Is there any way to specify to run android ndk app on performance core of snapdragon 820?

Tags: android, c++, performance, qualcomm

My android NDK app get slow periodically.
To confirm the reason is not by power saving core, I want to specify run on performance core.

NDK version is r14b.
development board is Open-Q snapdragon 820.

Comment: `sched_setaffinity` should work, probably.